# More than 2 condition in a for loop?

Tags: c++, c, for-loop

Was wondering if there is a way to compare 3-4 conditions in a for loop?
Is there a way to do this with just a for loop or would I need to add an if statement within the loop to control not printing 91 - 96?

I have tried adding an initial condition, brackets around both and around them all but cant seem to get it to print past 90 and pick up at 97.

```
for (int cntr = 65; cntr >= 65 && cntr < 91 || cntr > 96 && cntr < 122; cntr++)

for (int cntr = 65;  cntr < 91 || cntr > 96 && cntr < 122; cntr++)
```

Trying to print ASCII char for 65 through 122 without showing 90 through 96.
Was trying to get it all in one for loop if possible.

Comment: Remember that loops end as soon as the condition is false. You need to have an `if` inside the loop.

Comment: The loop condition is a _termination_ condition. At the moment it becomes false, the loop terminates. You cannot have "gaps".

Comment: Ok, makes sense. Thank You

Comment: I thought so but wasn't sure if there was a way around it. Thank you very much for clarifying this up for me.

Comment: don't use magic numbers like 65, 90, 96 or 122, no one knows what they mean. Use `'a'`, `'A'` or `'z'` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the central condition is a `break` condition.
As you want it all within one loop you don't want to break when you reach `cntr == 91`.

Here's a way to do it neatly in one loop (C++ style):

```
for (char cntr = 65; cntr < 123; cntr++)
{
    if ( cntr == 91 ) // skips the parts that you don't want
        cntr = 97;

    std::cout << cntr << std::endl;
}
```

More generally, there are times when you might have multiple genuine break conditions in a loop, but it's best to keep some/most of them out of the first line of the for loop, ie.  `for ( ... ; ... ; ... )`, as it's unnecessary and often is harder to read. You can just write a break condition at the start of your loop (ie. line 2):

```
for ( i = 0; break_condition_1; ++i)
{
    if ( break_condition_2 || break_condition_3 )
        break;

    // loop code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so fixed it like this:

```
for (int cntr = 65; cntr < 123; cntr++)
    {
        if(!(cntr >= 91 && cntr <= 96))
        cout << "#" << cntr << " = ASCII Char: " << char(cntr) << endl;
    }
```

Guess this is the best way to solve the issue for now.
Thank You again

Answer (score 0):

The answers above/below have explained it quite well about how you can go about having multiple for loop conditions.

But say you are doing something like this (as suggested by Elliott Smith):

```
for ( i = 0; break_condition_1; ++i)
{
    if ( break_condition_2 || break_condition_3 )
        break;

    // loop code
}
```

It might be better to simply do this for clarity reasons:

```
int i = 0;
while (break_condition_1 || break_condition_2 || break_condition_3){
   i++;
}
```

There is no major difference between for and while loops, aside from the fact for loop is neater to write in certain situations. In your case, I would recommend the while loop.

Comment: `while` equivalent to your `for` loop is `while(break_condition_1 && !(break_condition_2 || break_condition_3))`